# Get Array from Nifti File using PyVista

Tags: arrays, data-visualization, vtk, nifti, pyvista

im new to programming and im working with a MRI dataset (.nii) in PyVista 
Im trying read the Nifti File and extract an array so i can compare two MRIs based on the differences in the array and visualise it with PyVista. 
PyVista is mostly based on the VTK library so maybe there is a function in VTK but im a bit helpless looking through the Docs. 
I found a solution in nibabel to access an array:

```
img = nib.load(example_filename)

a = np.array(img.dataobj)
```

But with that i still can't access the PyVista Array to highlight the differences. 
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: This question is a bit broad as it is right now. PyVista indeed doesn't support Nifti files at the moment. [In July you asked about this in github discussions and you got a VTK-based workaround](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/discussions/2971), so at least the reading part should be solved for now (and there's a corresponding feature request to support this natively in PyVista). So the next question is if you have a well-formed idea of what you actually want to plot, and it seems to me this is not yet clear to you. So this question is not very easy for others to answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My idea is to read the Nifti File, extract the array, find the differences and highlight these with colour in a 3D plot. I would just need a function that gives me the array after reading it with the NIFTIImagereader.

Comment: Matthew Flamm's solution you accepted in discussions gives you "read the Nifti File". The `mesh` you get there is a PyVista mesh, presumably a `pyvista.UniformGrid` or similar. You can look at `mesh.cell_data` for "voxel" information, access arrays in there based on name. If you have two of these meshes with the same size you can just subtract the two data arrays to get a third data array. Then plot it in some way; "3D plot" is often hard to do, perhaps you could an opacity-based volumetric plot, or maybe look at cross-sections. Again this depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

We need to perform two distinct operations:

1. retrieving the intensity values from your NIfTI dataset using, for instance, *nibabel*
2. plotting the 3D numpy array using, for instance, *PyVista*. Take a look at the PyVista documentation [here](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/00-load/create-uniform-grid.html) and [here](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/02-plot/volume.html) for further details. You will have to add origin, spacing, etc. but for the sake of simplicity I am going to omit them.

Here is the code:

```py
import nibabel as nb

example = nb.load("/nifti/path/example.nii.gz")
intensities = example.get_fdata()

grid = pv.UniformGrid()
grid.dimensions = np.array(values.shape) + 1
grid.cell_data["intensities"] = intensities.flatten(order="F")
grid.plot(volume=True, cmap="bone")
```

Comment: We actually merged [a PR for NIFTI support](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/pull/3284) this week. Loading directly with pyvista should be possible with the next release (0.37).

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні any idea when that next release is? It seems to be an irregular release schedule

Comment: @lucasgoddamn tentative plan is about a month from now.